# How do I seperate Socket.io route code into different files

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Say you have a `server.js` like this:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var userDetails = {};


    /*
    Connection (after login)
     */
    socket.on('userData', function (userDetails) {
        users[userDetails.id] = socket;
        userDetails = userDetails;
        require('user-online.js').register(socket, userDetails);
    });



    //Notification
    socket.on('sendNotification', function (users, notification) {
       users.forEach(function (y) {
            if(users[y] != null){
                users[y].emit(notification);
            }
       })

    });



    socket.emit('newNotification', 'hell');

    socket.emit('someEvent', 'hello world');

    socket.on('browserClose', function (msg) {
        console.log('this user has disconnect: ' + userDetails.username);
        users[userDetails.id] = null;
    });



    //check connection / status of other sockets:

    socket.on('isOnline', function(user_id){
        socket.emit('userStatus', users[user_id] != null);
    });

    socket.on('setMyLocation', function(location){
        users[userDetails.id].location = location;
    });
});
```

i wont bother putting all the above things in where it connects since it has nothing to do with my question.

My question is basically this server.js file can get quite messy when more code is added. I would like to split the tasks of my socket into different javascript  files. However i am unsure how they work and i simply cannot seem to find any examples of this anywhere.

my idea is to have a handler for the following tasks:

- Notifications
- Chat
- Upload / download file

Can anyone push me in the right direction or does anyone have some documentation?

Comment: This is a rather good description of how to use "Modules" http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/. Modules will let you put code into another file and then you can `require(module_name)` it to access the exported variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a module to manage connections from client that i named "client-management":

```
var ClientManagement = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.messageListeners = [];
    /**
     * Add a messsage listener(require a onClientMessage(data,socket) function in the listener)
     * @param listener
     */
    this.addMessageListener = function(listener) {
        this.messageListeners.push(listener);
    };
    this.onMessage = function(data, socket) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.messageListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                this.messageListeners[i].onClientMessage(data, socket);
            } catch (exc) {

            }
        }
    };
   this.start=function(){
        var io = require('socket.io')(8080);
        io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {               
            /**
             * Receive message from client
             */
            socket.on('message', function(data) {
                self.onMessage(data, socket);
            });
        });
    });
  }
module.exports = new ClientManagement();
```

Use this module:

```
var clientManagementModule = require('./modules/client-management.js');
clientManagementModule.start();
var notificationModule = require('./modules/notification.js');
var chatModule = require('./modules/chat.js');
clientManagementModule.addMessageListener(notificationModule);
clientManagementModule.addMessageListener(chatModule);
```

Comment: You have the io.on('connect') in the clientmangement module how would your route to this location also how would you create serveral of such modules ?